# CoreData transformable type - can I store NSString or NSData?

Tags: ios, core-data

Here's the situation. I need to store either NSData (an image) or a string which will be used to pull an image from the bundle. Is this legal?

```
if(aCondition){
    [managedObject setValue:filePath forKey:imageKey];
}else{
    [managedObject setValue:imageData forKey:imageKey];
}
```

If this is legal, when it comes time to retrieve this info how can I determine what type of value I had originally saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the type NSData (binary), so save both that way. Assuming the path can never be more than some bytes long (say 128) and that an image has to be more than say 500 bytes, you can make the decision when the property is requested to transform it to a string or leave it as data.

If you don't like that approach, add a boolean and use it to indicate the type of the data.